# PHP, отфильтровать массив по похожему значению

Tags: php, сортировка

у меня есть данный массив

```
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(21) "113-8583167-1223425-1"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(19) "113-8583167-1223425"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(21) "113-8583167-1223425-2"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(19) "113-8701012-8931406"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(21) "113-1610353-3061845-1"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(19) "114-4039674-6828204"
}
array(1) {
  ["item_id"]=>
  string(19) "114-3749919-4620238"
}
```

мне нужно отфильтровать массив по похожим элементам
Похожими элементами являются

```
113-8583167-1223425
113-8583167-1223425-1
113-8583167-1223425-2
```

мне нужно оставить только `113-8583167-1223425-2` значение

Как это можно реализовать? Какой лучше алгоритм для этого использовать

Comment: Вы для начала определитесь, вам нужно отсортировать или отфильтровать значения?

Comment: да, извините, отфильтровать

Comment: Ну и сформулируй критерий похожести.

Comment: > Какой лучше алгоритм для этого использовать
foreach

Comment: вы задачу разбейте на части 1) как разделить строку на части, чтобы выделить эту концовку 1-2-3. 2) проходите по исходному массиву, разбиавайте строку. Основную часть делайте ключом, а концовку ищите максимальную. 3) слейте все обратно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно таким способом, если начальный формат отвечает маске **xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx**, а там если что то только маску поправить:

```
$array = [
    ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-1'],
    ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425'],
    ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-2'],
    ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406'],
    ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406-1'],
    ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-1'],
    ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-25'],
    ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-7'],
    ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-5'],
    ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-9'],
];

$array = array_unique(array_column($array, 'item_id'));

rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

$uniques[] = array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $search = $item;
    if (0 !== preg_match('/(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)\-\d+/', $item, $match)) {
        list($original, $search) = $match;
    }

    $isUnique = true;
    foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
        if (strpos($unique, $search) !== false) {
            $isUnique = false;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (true === $isUnique) {
        $uniques[] = $item;
    }
}

$map = array_map(
    function ($value) {
        return ['item_id' => $value];
    },
    $uniques
);

var_dump($map);
```

Масив на выходе: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код работает отлично, но если поставить после маски xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx, любую цыфру выше 9 то работает не правильно.

А так спасибо!

Comment: Тогда можно поправить регулярку вод так ```/(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)\-\d+/``` и все заработает

Comment: не помогает я пробывал менять регулярку
проблема заключается скорее в другом

Comment: А какие значения вы пробуете, можно пример, постараюсь адаптировать.

Comment: $array = [
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-2'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-25'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-7'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-5'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-9'],
        ];

Comment: Ага, оно как строку сортировало, поэтому хватить просто добавить флаг в функцию **rsort()**  rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL); , исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой рабочий вариант

```
 $arrayItems = array();

        $array = [
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8583167-1223425-2'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406'],
            ['item_id' => '113-8701012-8931406-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-1'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-25'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-7'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-5'],
            ['item_id' => '113-1610353-3061845-9'],
            ['item_id' => '114-4039674-6828204'],
            ['item_id' => '114-3749919-4620238'],
            ['item_id' => '114-3749919-4620238-111'],
        ];
        $array = array_unique(array_column($array, 'item_id'));
        rsort($array);

        echo "<pre>";
        foreach($array as $data){
            $itemExplode = explode('-', $data);
            $item = $itemExplode[0] . '-' . $itemExplode[1] . '-' . $itemExplode[2];

            if($itemExplode[3] > $arrayItems[$item]) $arrayItems[$item] = $itemExplode[3];
            elseif (!array_key_exists($item, $arrayItems) AND is_null($itemExplode[3])) $arrayItems[$item] = $itemExplode[3];
        }

        var_dump($arrayItems);
```